# how to hide padding in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to hide with `hidden-xs` in Bootstrap just the padding. How would I be able to remove just the padding without removing the whole row ? thanks in advance!

I have something like this

```
<td class="paddingleftTenHiddenXS col-lg-8" style="padding-left:10px; ">
```

Comment: `hidden-xs` hides a grid cell only. you may include `<div class='row'>` inside to make 0px on left and right sides. And it's strange that you're using `<td>` - maybe your task has more simple solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css:

```
div.special > div[class*="col-"] {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="row special">
    <div class="col-xs-8"> content... </div>
</div>
```

div.special > div[class*="col-"] targets all children of the special class that have a class that starts with "col-" you could also make it "col-xs-" to target extra small

*edited